Unable to Connect to Apache Derby Database in Eclipse: "org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver" Not Found
I'm trying to set up a connection to an Apache Derby database in Eclipse, but I keep encountering the following error:
Connection Error
Ping Error
I am able to connect and create a database via Windows 10 Command Prompt. But it seems like Eclipse doesn't find Derby here.
So when creating a new database connection I just use the default settings, where it should create a db named "sample" with "user" as user name and password.
I select the right JAR at the driver definitions.
I also added all needed JARs in the Java Build Path Class Variables and set the environment variables
I also started the server, of course running on the right port. As I said, running on Command Prompt works fine, but not in Eclipse.
Anyone know what I am missing? Tried everything, but I'm out of ideas right now.

Can you show that the variable you've defined is on the project's Build Path?

@nitind It has nothing to do with the project. I just want to make a general database connection via Eclipse Data Source Explorer

It's not wrong when it says that that class can't be found; no such class exists in 10.17.1.0's derbyclient.jar. It's in derbytools.jar.
Your mention of the classpath variable is irrelevant unless you're writing an application.

Oh, damn.. that worked.
